# why can't my <router-view> be rendered?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am a noob to vue-router. Here is my code,I want to render User compoent, when I navigate to http://localhost:8080/users

App.vue file:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{msg}}</h1>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Users.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>xue yan</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Users from './Users.vue'

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {path:'/users',component:Users}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

But, I can't see the Users component in my index.html,when I try to navigate to "http://localhost:8080/users".All the files come from vue-cli webpack-simple. what's more, there is no error in console.I can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You need to have the script section in Users.vue, and try to export empty object there - `export default { //... }`

Comment: @BelminBedak thats not compulsory , template element alone is enough to render a component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add history mode to your router  as follows

```
const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history',
    routes,
 });
```

Without history mode on you need to add # in your search like this **http://localhost:8080/#/users** to make it work.

More about why history mode read the docs [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)